# How to get an approximation of $P(A\leq \max_{1\leq i\leq n}B_i)$,where $A, B_i$ are independent Gaussian random variables

Tags: probability

Consider the independent Gaussian random variables,
$A$, $B_1$,...,$B_n$. $B_i$ is distributed as $N(0,1)$. They are all independent.
$A$ is distributed as $N(m,1)$.
How can I approximate the probability
$P(A\leq \max_{1\leq i\leq n} B_i)$

I am interested in the large n regime, and if we allow m to scale with n, how should m scale with n such that the probability will converges to zero, for large n.

Comment: Let $\phi, \Phi$ be the density function and the cumulative distribution function resp. of the standard normal variable.

Set $S : = \max_{1\leq i\leq n} B_i$, then
$F_S(t) := \mathbb{P}(S\leq t) = \mathbb{P}(B_i \leq t, \forall i \leq n) = \big[ \Phi(t) \big]^n$ by independence.

And  the desired probability can be rewritten as
$$\mathbb{P}( A - m \leq S - m ) = \mathbb{E}\big[ \Phi(S-m) \big] $$ 
by first conditioning on $S$;
$$ = \int_{-\infty}^\infty  \Phi(t-m) d F_s(t) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty  \Phi(t-m)\cdot \big[ n \cdot \Phi(t)^{n-1} f(t)   \big] dt$$ So is this enough for ur purpose ?

Comment: btw, why did you label this question " Gaussian-integral" ?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am interested in the large n and m regime. Under what conditions, i.e., how m should scale with n, such that this probability will converge to zero as n goes to infinity.